# Iterate over a portion of a list in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, list-comprehension

I'd like to print out the first 10 lines of a file and avoid reading in any extra lines. How can I do that with a list comprehension without reading in the whole file?

I know that I can do the code like this:

```
N = 10
with open(path,'rb') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print line.strip()
        N -= 1
        if N == 0:
            break
```

But I think a list comprehension is more appropriate:

```
with open(path,'rb') as f_in:
    [print line for i, line in enumerate(f_in) if i<N]
```

However, that doesn't work because of the print statement so i end up with this mess:

```
with open(path,'rb') as f_in:
    lines = [line.strip() for i, line in enumerate(f_in) if i<N]
    for line in lines:
        print line
```

And the real point of my question is how do you get the list comprehension to stop when i==N instead of needlessly continuing and only filtering out the extra lines?

Is there a way to limit how far into an iterator a list comprehension will go? And is there an appropriate way to print out from a list comprehension? I'm fairly new to python and so I'm trying to learn how to do things the right way rather than just the first way I can think of it. I'd like to able to write this in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do you get the list comprehension to stop when i==N instead of
>   needlessly continuing and only filtering out the extra lines?
>   Is there a way to limit how far into an iterator a list comprehension will go?

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to iterate over a slice of an iterable:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(path,'rb') as f_in:
    for line in islice(f_in, N):
        print line.strip()
```

Actually you can specify the index of the first line to produce and even a step (like list or string slicing).

Note that you shouldn't use a list-comprehension if you don't actually need a list, because it consumes memory (in your case you keep all the contents of the file in memory, which can be bad if the file is big).
If you simply want to iterate once over something use a generator expression:

```
lines = (line.strip() for line in f_in)
```

(Yes, you simply have to change the `[]` with `()`).
This avoids to building the whole list when executed.

> is there an appropriate way to print out from a list comprehension?

*No*.

In python2 `print` is a statement and thus it cannot be present in an expression
In python3 you *could* call `print` since it is a function, but it is a *very bad idea*.

List-comprehensions have a specific purpose: build a list from a given iterable.
You are throwing the list away, thus defeating the whole purpose of that syntax.

*For this reason* there is no support for "breaking" out of the loop in a list-comprehension. If you have a code so complex to require a `break` you'd better write it with an explicit `for` loop.

The same is true if you tried to do something like calling `map`:

```
map(lambda line: print line, lines)
```

<sup>Assuming the it would be possible to insert a `print` in a `lambda`</sup>

This even *fails* in python3 (it wont print anything).

If you want to write good python code the number one rule is to follow the language design:
don't mix expression and statements, that is to say: use expression return values, don't abuse them to produce side-effects.

Comment: I used the itertools islice option and went with the proper for loop. I'll keep your advice in mind about following the language design.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call [next()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_next.htm) on the file object in the range of lines you require:

```
lines = [f_in.next() for x in range(10)]
```

This will give you the first ten lines.

Using `next()` can be useful if you want to skip headers or other lines at the start of your file. Each time you call next on the file object you will move to the next line of the file.

If you wanted to print the contents of lines you could use `join()`:

```
print "".join(lines)
```